# Sort collections with objects with float value

Tags: java, list, object, collections, comparator

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Area{
  String id;
  Float value;
  int startTime;
  int endTime;
  Map<Integer, List<scheduleRequest>> timeSlotMap;
}
```

I want to sort the area based on the value which is a float number.

I tried this:

```
class Value implements Comparator<Area>{

  @Override
  public int compare(Area a1, Area a2) {
       return (int)(a1.value-a2.value); I also tried this
  }
}
```

And in main

```
    Area area1=new Area();
    area1.value=(float) 1.0;
    Area area2=new Area();
    area2.value=(float) 0.8;
    Area area3=new Area();
    area3.value=(float) 0.6;
    List<Area> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(area2,area1,area3));
    Collections.sort(list, new Value());
```

However, the list is not sorted.

Comment: You set area1.value three times.  Try setting area2.value and area3.value.

Comment: I edit the question, please see again. @ShearPlane

Comment: Just as a quick note, usually you will see float values as `1.0f` instead of explicit casts `(float)1.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

`Math.round(a1.value-a2.value);`

Instead of:

`(int)(a1.value-a2.value);`

Answer (score 1):

Here `-`  should be replaced with `,`

```
class Value implements Comparator<Area>{

  @Override
  public int compare(Area a1, Area a2) {
       return Float.compare(a1.value, a2.value); // try it now
  }
}
```

It will work when `a1.value, a2.value` should be float values

Answer (score 0):

Change your main() method to

```
Area area1=new Area();
area1.value=(float) 1.0;
Area area2=new Area();
area2.value=(float) 0.8;  // area2 instead of area1
Area area3=new Area();
area3.value=(float) 0.6;  // area3 instead of area1
List<Area> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(area2,area1,area3));
Collections.sort(list, new Value());
```

Comment: @user6119494 Your cast rounds the result of the subtraction.  Please use `Float.compare(float, float)` as noted in the answer from BlackJoker too.

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead implementing `Comparator`, implement `Comparable`

2) You don't need to pass a `Comparator` to the call to `Collections.sort`, just pass the list:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

3) You should check for nulls properly in your `compareTo()` method to prevent these type of errors. If a1.value or a2.values is null, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown. It would be better to check for null in advance.

Comment: why using comparable instead of comparator?

Comment: Because if your object is Comparable, passing around a Comparator becomes unnecessary. Any sort will know that your object is Comarable and call the compareTo method for you.